# Is one degree of freedom in 3D redundant?

Tags: rotations, classical-mechanics

In 3D, you can get a z-axis rotation by composing rotations using the other 2 axis.

For instance, using a 5-axis CNC machine, you can get your object in any orientation.

Why is there 6 degrees of freedom if 5 are enough?

Comment: If you mean rotations only (as opposed to including translations), there are actually only 3 degrees of freedom, for example, Euler angles.

Comment: Yes, there are 3 degrees of freedom for translations. However, why is there 3 degrees of freedom for rotations if you can get a z-axis rotation by composing rotations using the other 2 axis? Shouldn't it be only 2 degrees of freedom for rotations?

Comment: Degrees of freedom means how many numbers you need to describe an arbitrary rotation. You need 3 numbers, such as Euler angles. You can't describe it with only two. The fact that z-axis rotation can be expressed in terms of rotation around the other axes doesn't help you get rid of a number.

Comment: I understand, thanks. It's interesting that you can't get a z-axis translation using the other 2 axis, but you can with rotations. That's why a 5-axis CNC machine is enough to get the object in any orientation.